# Liferay 7 MVC Portlet - Where to locate javascript when using the new lr module approach

Tags: javascript, directory, liferay

does someone know a good example which shows where to locate javascript and css in a MVC portlet in LR7 and load it by annotation "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portal-javascript"?

Thanks for a short hin.

Best regards

Udo

Answer (score 1):

Best example is Liferay's source code. See for example [ServerAdminPortlet](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-server/blob/9d3e77a9751c4b8b7b371142c3e7d020bfb1497b/server-admin-web/src/main/java/com/liferay/server/admin/web/internal/portlet/ServerAdminPortlet.java#L32) which uses `com.liferay.portlet.footer-portlet-javascript` pointing to `/js/main.js` which you can find in [`<PORTLET's_SRC_FOLDER>/resources/META-INF/resources/`](https://github.com/liferay/com-liferay-server/tree/9d3e77a9751c4b8b7b371142c3e7d020bfb1497b/server-admin-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/js)

Comment: Hello Milen! Thanks again. That was what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Milen, does the js have to be in a special form for e.g. wrapped with AUI.add{} or can I use any javascript I want? I'm trying to load a small angular app with my extension but for any reason I don't see the according files included. Are the contents of the js files combined to on big js file?

Comment: It should work for any js. There are no restrictions I'm aware of. Double check the name and the path.

Comment: Did it and the name / path matches: The property "com.liferay.portlet.footer-portal-javascript=/js/liferay.run.js" and the file is named "liferay.run.js" and is located unter .../resources/META-INF/resources/js/liferay.run.js. I'm running out of ideas. Is there a possibility to track the processing of the property with a debugger? Only do see what happens.

Comment: Milen, I got it working now but without the annotation. Instead I adapted directly the view.jsp and the scripts are found. It seems that it is depending on the annotation. I have similar problems with the service builder annotations for rest services. I won't say that both cases are linked to each other but its really strange that this problems come always up on annotations.